# Intersecting Angles of Three Planes

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

There are three planes, **A**, **B**, and **C**, all of which intersect at a single point, **P**. The angles between the planes are given: $$\angle\mathbf{AB}=\alpha$$ $$\angle\mathbf{BC}=\beta$$ $$\angle\mathbf{CA}=\gamma$$ $$0\lt\alpha,\beta,\gamma\le\frac{\pi}{2}$$

The intersection of any two of these planes form lines. The intersection of **AB** is $\mathbf{\overline{AB}}$, the intersection of **BC** is $\mathbf{\overline{BC}}$, and the intersection of **CA** is $\mathbf{\overline{CA}}$. It is given that none of these lines are parallel to each other and that they all intersect at the same single point, **P**.

Please express the lesser of the two angles formed by the intersection of these lines in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$:
$$\angle\mathbf{\overline{AB}\;\overline{BC}}=?$$ $$\angle\mathbf{\overline{AB}\;\overline{CA}}=?$$ $$\angle\mathbf{\overline{BC}\;\overline{CA}}=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$, are unit vectors perpendicular to $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{C}$, then $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}$ is a vector of magnitude $\sin\alpha$ directed along line $\overline{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}}$, and so on. The quantity $(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})\cdot(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})$ is then proportional to the cosine of $\angle\overline{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}}\ \overline{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}}$:
$$
(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})\cdot(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})=
\sin\alpha\sin\beta
\cos(\angle\overline{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}}\ \overline{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}}).
$$
On the other hand, according to [a well-know vector identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Addition_and_multiplication):
$$
(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})\cdot(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})=
(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})\cdot(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})-
(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})\cdot(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b})=
\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\gamma.
$$
It follows that
$$
\cos(\angle\overline{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}}\ \overline{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}})=
\left|{\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\gamma\over\sin\alpha\sin\beta}\right|,
$$
where I inserted the absolute value in order to pick the lower angle.

Comment: If I assign a coordinate system such that plane $\mathbf{A}$ is the $\mathbf{xy}$ plane and $\mathbf{B}$ intersects $\mathbf{A}$ along the $\mathbf{x}$ axis, I can get the normal vectors for $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, and I can make the origin point $\mathbf{P}$. The problem now is that I cannot see how to get the normal vector for plane $\mathbf{C}$ because I don't know where it is in relation to the other two planes. I only know the angles it makes with the other planes and that it contains the point $\mathbf{P}$, which is the origin.

Comment: You needn't use the coordinates. I'll add some detail in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the last mentioned angles as $a,b,c$ and the spherical triangle $ABC$ then from Spherical Trigonometry (sphere has center at $P$,) the Law of Sines is valid:

$$ \dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\sin a} = \dfrac{\sin \beta}{\sin b} =\dfrac{\sin \gamma}{\sin c}= \dfrac{6\, Volume\, PABC}{\sin a\sin b\sin c }  $$